# App will crash if set navigation bar large title color to named color

Tags: ios, xcode9

I recently start use the new color set feature and today I try to edit all colors in my storyboard, suddenly my app crashes after pushing to one of the view.

Error log:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Then I try to set those colors back and found out that the navigation bar large title color will cause this crash.

This will CRASH:

[image: This will CRASH]

This works fine:

[image: This works fine]

Now I am thinking that should I keep using this color set function or not cause it seems not reliable enough. Maybe someday it will crash again in another place and I have to check all the object in my code or storyboard 1-by-1.

Anyone face this?

Comment: How you are setting Navigation title? Programatically? or using storyboard?

Comment: Maybe because named colors; i.e. those defined in the asset catalog are supported only iOS11+ onwards.

Comment: @SaqibOmer Using storyboard

Comment: @staticVoidMan It only happens when setting title color in navigation view controller, other view controllers works fine~.

Comment: @Rice If I could replicate your crash then maybe I could look into it and help find a solution. Would you update your question with the bare minimum code/setup to achieve this crash?

Comment: Having the same issue, is there any solution? It does work with SDK Colors but crashes as soon i select a custom Color Assest

Comment: @staticVoidMan to achiev this crash just create a custom Color Assest and select it as Title color in a UINavigationBar (Storyboard)